# Adobe Indesign (CS6) exporting pngs/jpgs with custom filenames

Tags: adobe-indesign

Does anybody know an easy way to export images (pngs, jpgs, etc.) from Adobe Indesign (CS6) with custom filenames, like it is possible to do the same in Adobe Illustrator with custom filenames.